# How can I separate character strings in a tibble into new columns when the strings are of different classes?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a column in a tibble with entries in the form of 2XYZ005GHT108 and I want to separate them into 4 new columns: "2XYZ", "005", "GHT", and "108". My entries don't include delimiters. I don't know what to input as the sep = argument in the separate() function in tidyr.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = c("2XYZ005GHT108", "4T005N108"))
df %>% 
  separate(x, C("Product", "Size", "Country", "Pall"), sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: So if you don't have delimiters, how do you intend to split strings? What's your logic?

Comment: It's a code generated in a system to describe articles on a production line- each snippet of code means something to engineers who can read it but I need to separate it for analysis purposes- to see everything from a specific country, or only specific products, etc-

Comment: But what's the pattern you need to use to separate it? That's the part that's unclear, especially since you only included 1 example of the output

Answer (score 3):

**1) separate** If the fields can be of variable length but we know that the second and fourth are all digits and consist of at least 2 characters and the other fields contain no more than one digit in a row and will not have a digit adjacent to an all digit field then we can replace any string of 2 or more digits with a space, that same string and another space.  Then we can use `separate`. The `gsub` will place a space at the end indicating a 5th field is expected, though not present,  so absorb that using a field of NA in the `separate` statement.  (`Alternately use the  extra = "drop"` argument to `separate`.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = gsub("(\\d\\d+)", " \\1 ", x)) %>%
  separate(x, c("Product", "Size", "Country", "Pall", NA))
## # A tibble: 2 x 4
##   Product Size  Country Pall 
##   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>
## 1 2XYZ    005   GHT     108  
## 2 4T      005   N       108
```

**2) read.pattern** We can alternately use `read.pattern` assuming that the first field is a digit followed by non-digits, the second field is digits, the third ends in a non-digit and the fourth is digits.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "^(\\d\\D+)(\\d+)(.*\\D)(\\d+)"
read.pattern(text = df$x, pattern = pat, colClasses = "character",
  col.names = c("Product", "Size", "Country", "Pall"))
##   Product Size Country Pall
## 1    2XYZ  005     GHT  108
## 2      4T  005       N  108
```

**2a) strcapture** This can also be done using only base R by using `pat` defined above with `strcapture` like this:

```
strcapture(pat, df$x, list(Product = character(0), Size = character(0),
  Country = character(0), Pall = character(0)))
##   Product Size Country Pall
## 1    2XYZ  005     GHT  108
## 2      4T  005       N  108
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have so much to learn in R, this really helps.

Comment: I couldn't get the gsubfn package to load (tried downloading it from github but still can't seem to get R to find it, that's how much of a newbie I am)- but strcapture works great on my real data, so thank you again!

Comment: You can install it from CRAN.  `install.packages("gsubfn")` . If that does not work there is likely something fundamentally wrong with your R installation possibly related to the tcltk package which normally is part of base R.

Comment: There are some notes related to gsubfn and tcltk in the section *How do I install tcltk?* at this link https://code.google.com/archive/p/gsubfn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` for this purpose. For more information see `?substr`

```
df %>% mutate(Product = substr(x, 1,4), Size = substr(x, 5,7))
```

if length of your string is not fixed, check answer from @g-grothendieck